# how to pass a http response from component to another in angular

Tags: angular, api, service

i cannot update the data

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private data1 = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  data = this.data1.asObservable();
  data3:any;
  constructor() { }
  sendData(data: any) {
    this.data1.next(data);
  }
  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.data;
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts` file:

```
public postData(name: string) {
  const headers = { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" };
  this.http.post("http://localhost:5000/app/", name, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.data = response;
        },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
}
```

`parcourir.component.ts` file:

```
export class ParcourirComponent implements OnInit{ 
  data1:any;
  constructor(private service:DataService){}
  ngOnInit() {  
    this.service.getData().subscribe(response=>{
      this.data1 = response;
      console.log(this.data1)
    });
}
```

It logs null to  the console, it's not updating data
i want the response get in the http request in `app.component.ts` to be sent to `parcourir.component.ts`.

Comment: Most likely you are subscribing after the data has been set. Besides, you should use a `Subject` rather than a `BehaviorSubject` since you're initializing it with a null and not useful data.

Comment: i tried with subject, and it shows the same result. How to make it subscribe before the data has been sent?

Comment: It depends on your project structure. Anyway, if the log of the ParcourirComponent its called before the console.log in the subscribe you know for sure. Anyway, `sendData` is never called so you're never actually updating the value of your BS, hence the subscription will never catch the data got from the api call.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `data` variable as a `BehaviorSubject` then update it like below (in `app.component.ts`):

```
this.service.data.next(newValue);
```

Finally in the destination component you can subscribe to the value change of the `data` field this way (in `parcourir.component.ts`):

```
this.service.data.asObservable().subscribe((value) => {
  this.localDataField = value;
});
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: in the service layer you have to use `next()` to set the value. in the components you import the service and in `ngOnInit()` you subscribe to the value change. remember to `unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` to avoid memory leak. @user21681228

Comment: Thank you for your help, but, i used query string and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most ideally it would look like this:

data.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  data$: Observable<any> = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  updateData(data: any) {
    this.dataSubject.next(data) 
  }

  fetchData(name: string): void {
    const headers = { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" };
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:5000/app/", { name }, { headers })
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name: string = 'YourName';

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.postData();
  }

  postData() {
    this.dataService.fetchData(this.name).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.dataService.updateData(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );;
  }
}
```

parcourir.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parcourir',
  templateUrl: './parcourir.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parcourir.component.css']
})
export class ParcourirComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.data$.subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: i tried that before and it doesn't work

Comment: Try it with the updated answer

Comment: it didn't work also, and, it shows errors

Comment: can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: yes, give me an email to send it to you